# How to Create Folders in a SharePoint Wiki Library?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, wiki

In Team Foundation Server 2010 Team Project Portal how can I create sub-folders in the Wiki section?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: The version that installed with TFS Sharepoint 3

Comment: @u07ch: You can use Sharepoint 2010 with TFS2010 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wiki functionality is just a Sharepoint functionality. Adding folders is not available by default in a SP Wikisite. For a workaround, read http://sharepointpratik.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/create-folder-in-wiki-page-library/

Comment: Thanks for this - it was this page that actually spurned the question. I can't find the Wiki Page in Windows Explorer and there doesn't seem to be an option in the site to find it. Doing a search finds 4 folders but none are the right one :(

Comment: You know how to open up Windows explorer from the Wiki library? What version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: Open up "Explorer View" by clicking on the action menu and choosing "Open with Windows Exporer". If that option is not available, you might be experiencing one of the many client integration issues of SP.

Comment: Can you add the relevant portions of the workaround from the link to make this a more complete answer?

Answer (score 12):

Customize the Wiki
Goto Advanced Settings and enable Make New Folder option.. tada!

Answer (score 2):

Do the following.

1. Open settings menu for a library:
   [image]
2. Find advanced settings:
   [image]
3. In advanced settings find "Make 'New folder' command available" and choose 'Yes'. Confirm your settings.
   [image]
4. Go back to your page library and evidence 'Folder' command in 'New' menu:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

For some versions of SharePoint, you can also grant *Manage Hierarchy* permissions to the user and/or group, then you can use a “/” in your link and SharePoint will automatically create the folder for you.

For example, the link might be *[[SubFolder/Home|Home Page for Sub Folder]]*, which will create the Home page in the folder named SubFolder.

Perform the following steps:

1. Click to Site Actions.
2. Click Site Settings.
3. Click Site permissions.
4. Check the box next to the user or group of interest.
5. Click Edit User Permissions.
6. Check the Manage Hierarchy box.
7. Click OK.